# Transferring an old domain with an existing site to a new site

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system, web-hosting, registrar

Peculiar problem, I have a client with a site they would like to replace. The site being so old that the company's that provide the domain and hosting don't provide these services anymore. I managed to contact the company where the domain was registered and transfer the domain name to the google registrar but have had no luck in locating the provider for the hosting in order to transfer the site itself and thus gain control of it.

My question is: can you kill the old site that the domain links to or otherwise upload a new site to the domain without access to the hosting?

Answer (score 1):

If you got control of domain, it doesn't matter if the old site remains up.

Just point the domain to the new hosting server/folder as they tell you in their instructions and the old site will be inaccessible other than by IP address.

Comment: That's great thanks. Alternately, can you disable the existing site before setting up the new host? perhaps through the google registrar.